# Vowpal Wabbit model loading

Tags: model, vowpalwabbit

I'm a beginner in Machine Learning. I'm using Vowpal Wabbit for text classification using the python wrapper(pyvw). To save the pyvw model I'm using model.save(filename). But I don't know how to load the model for prediction. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 2):

To load the model you'll need to instantiate a `vw` instance with specific args. The following snippet will load a model from disk as part of the initialization.

```py
from vowpalwabbit import pyvw
model = pyvw.vw(initial_regressor="model_file.vw")
```